# Is there any way to trigger a DOM event for multiple forms at the same page?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom-events, contact-form-7

I recently coded an alert action for my forms in a WordPress site. It's working, but unfortunately only for the first form. If there is more than one form in the page, it's not getting triggered.

Is there any way to get it working for all forms of the page?

My code:

```php
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
        wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
            //if ('563' == event.detail.contactFormId) {
                var idform = event.detail.contactFormId;
                alert (idform);
            //}
        }, true );
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Form snippets:

```
[contact-form-7 id="556" title="test 1"]
```

```
[contact-form-7 id="563" title="test 2"]
```

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead and iterate over the resulting list of forms.

Comment: Did you mean this? `var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelectorAll( '.wpcf7' );` Because it´s not working form me.

Comment: Did you iterate over it? Or just add `All`? Because that alone won't be enough. You need `wpcf7Elm.forEach(function(form) {  form.addEventListener(...);  })`

Comment: That did it! Thank you! ^.^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the final code (credit to ***Chris G***):

```html
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelectorAll( '.wpcf7' );
        wpcf7Elm.forEach(function(formr){
        formr.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
                var idform = event.detail.unitTag;
                alert (idform);
        }, false ); })
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: this is inefficient as there are as many event handlers as forms on the page.  Better to use a event delegation

Answer (score 1):

CF7 [events](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/js/src/event.js) bubble up through the document, so you can do something like this,

```
let page = document.querySelector('body');
page.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function(e){
  let idform = e.detail.contactFormId;
  alert (idform);
});
```